# Recursion not available, but still gives answer

Tags: bind, recursive

I tried to dig a domain on a non-recursive DNS server. From what I know (so far), a non recursive DNS is not supposed to answer what they are not authoritative for.

For example :

```
[root@dhcppc14 vwxyz]# dig muse.mu @202.159.36.218

; <<>> DiG 9.8.2rc1-RedHat-9.8.2-0.30.rc1.el6_6.3 <<>> muse.mu @202.159.36.218
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 46239
;; flags: qr rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0
**;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available**

;; QUESTION SECTION:

;muse.mu.                       IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:

**muse.mu.                3600    IN      A       162.249.109.50**

;; Query time: 253 msec
;; SERVER: 202.159.36.218#53(202.159.36.218)
;; WHEN: Sat Jun 27 05:58:14 2015
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 41
```

Could you explain what exactly happened?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

*I'm not sure if `202.159.36.218` is supposed to be an authoritative nameserver for `muse.mu` or where it comes into the picture. Because of that I can't explain why `202.159.36.218` answers for `muse.mu` without being recursive.*

**The warning you're seeing is printed from `dig`whenever it sends a query with RD (recursion desired), and receives a response without RA (recursion available).**

`dig` sends recursive queries by default (message type RD, "recursion desired").

From the `dig` man page:

> +[no]recurse
>
> Toggle the setting of the RD (recursion desired) bit in the query. This bit is
> set by default, which means **dig normally sends recursive queries**. Recursion is
> automatically disabled when the +nssearch or +trace query options are used.

From [RFC 883](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc883#page-24):

> A name server that supports recursive service sets the Recursion
> Available (RA) bit in all responses it generates.  A requestor
> asks for recursive service by setting the Recursion Desired (RD)
> bit in queries.  In some situations where recursive service is the
> only path to the desired information (see below), the name server
> may go recursive even if RD is zero.

The warning will print whenever you query a authoritative nameserver where recursion is not allowed without specifying that the query is to be non-recursive (option `+norecurse`).

Comment: Hi mboehn thanks for your explanation. The ip address 202.159.36.218 is my nameserver, which of course not an authoritative for muse.mu. I was just curious if there was a misconfiguration with my bind. I found this also on another authoritative nameserver. Is there any possibility that the nameserver using its cache?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
dig +trace @202.159.36.218 muse.mu
```

to check how exactly resolving is goes in your case.

It either immediately returns a DNS record because it already stores it in local cache or directly queries a DNS Name Server which is authoritative for the record, meaning it definitely holds the correct IP for that hostname.